# Asrock motherboard - "Please select the boot device" screen freezes

Tags: boot, bios

Currently trying to boot my unraid server from usb. Set the boot options to usb as default. When I start I get the screen below which freezes. I cannot drag the mouse or click anything.

Someone an idea what could cause this?

[BIOS usb boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoMvd.jpg)

Details

- **Motherboard**: ASRock Z270M Pro4
- **Bios version**: P1.10
- **Legacy boot**

Comment: Please post Motherboard Model No. and BIOS version. Is UEFI enabled? Is legacy boot enabled? Can your computer boot other mediums?
You could try to burn the drive image onto a DVD, set the DVD-ROM drive as the first drive on the boot order, and boot from it.

Comment: I very much agree with Milo8505, more informaton would help a great deal. Are you sure that the USB is bootable? Have you tried it on any other machines?

Comment: mmm probably a usb error? I just pressed enter to see what would happen. Next screen states `non-system disk. Press any key to reboot`

Comment: That mean that probabbly, your USB is not bootable

Comment: Yes USB had issues. Remade the img and worked correctly. Thanks!